# Construct a triangle given its circumscribed circle and the three points on it...

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Construct a triangle given its circumscribed circle and the three points on it at which the altitude, the angle bisector and the median, drawn from the same vertex, intersect the circle.

The problem is from the book. I have copied the question exactly how the book has stated it including punctuations. Below is something I made as a quick "glance" of sorts. Red figures are the givens. [image].

Comment: Just because it's difficult? This is not a challenge site.

Comment: What have you attempted? Do you know that the angle bisector from $A$ meets the circumcircle at the midpoint of the $BC$ arc?

Comment: It is not difficult, by the way, you just have to exploit the previous lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Let $H_A,L_A,M_A$ be the points on the circumcircle given by the altitude, the angle bisector and the median through $A$. Let $O$ be the center of the circumcircle (i.e. the circumcenter of $ABC$).

[image]

1. The parallel to $O L_A$ through $H_A$ meets the circumcircle at $A$;
2. $AM_A$ and $OL_A$ meet at the midpoint of $BC$;
3. The perpendicular to $OL_A$ through the midpoint of $BC$ is the $BC$ side.

If you do not know which point lies on which cevian you have to consider that on the $BC$ side the foot of the angle bisector always lies between the foot of the altitude and the midpoint of the $BC$ side by the bisector theorem. It follows that there are at most two solutions associated with the labelings $(H_A,L_A,M_A)$ and $(M_A,L_A,H_A)$:

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to assume you know WHICH of the three points is the one where the altitude intersects the circle, WHICH is where the angle bisector intersects the circle, and WHICH is where the median intersects the circle. In order to know that, either it must be given or it must be deducible from the locations of the three points. Whether it is given seems unclear from the question, and whether it is deducible is not addressed in the answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: on the $BC$ side the feet of the angle bisector is always between the foot of the median and the foot of the altitude, hence there are only two possible solutions.

Comment: I guess the only problem with this proof is it knows which one otherwise its sound for me. I'm still a student though so yeah. hahaha. But I get it.